# VueJS V3 - render dynamic compoment

Tags: vue.js

Trying to understand how to dynamically render components into my parent page.
I'm assuming I will have an array of objects, where each object has a component name and data fields that bind to the parameters in the object.  This suggests if one component repeats two or more times on the page, the field binding must be unique to the component instance.

Below I'm getting an error that reads:

"[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. at  at  at "

After hours of reading and trials and errors, I have to give up for now and ask for help.  Here is my code:

**default.html**

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Agenda to Minutes</title>
            <!-- Import Styles -->
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles.css" /> -->
            <!-- Import Vue.js -->
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div id="app">
        
                htmlData: {{htmlData}} <br>
                this.htmlData: {{this.htmlData}} <br>
                    
                <dynamic-one></dynamic-one>
        
            </div>
        
            <!-- Import App -->
            <script src="./main.js"></script>
        
            <!-- Import Components -->
            <script src="./components/dynamicOne.js"></script>
        
            <!-- Mount App -->
            <script>
                app.component('my-dynamic-component',{/* defination */})
                const mountedApp = app.mount('#app')
        
                _this = mountedApp;
                _this.htmlData = '<div>Hello - {{someVar}}</div>'
        
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

my **component page**

```
        app.component('dynamic-one', {
            props: {
                templateHtml: {
                    templateHtml: true,
                    type: String
                }
            },
        
            data() {
                return {
                    someVar: 'Test',
                    htmlData:'xyz'
                }
            },
            template:
                /*html*/
                <div>
                    <!-- _this.htmlData: {{_this.htmlData}} -->
        
                dynamicOne : {{this.htmlData}}
        
                    <my-dynamic-component :template-html="htmlData" />
                </div>,
        
            created() {
                this.$options.template = this.templateHtml
            }
        })
```

**main.js**

````
    
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    htmlData: 'myName'
                }
            }
        })
```
````

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here.
You're trying to dynamically assign HTML (the template of your component)?
You can use [slots](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) for that case.
Vue will transform 'template' into render functions, which you basically circumvent the way you're trying to assign it, thus it will error saying that you neither have a template or render function present.
You could of course try using [render functions](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#the-dom-tree) instead to create dynamic elements.

Comment: if you want to avoid the warn just add the `template` prop to `my-dynamic-component`